# Creating a Visual Studio 2010 add-in with a user-interface?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How can I create a Visual Studio 2010 add-in with a user-interface? I want my add-in to have a window that can be pinned, just like the "Output", "Task list", "Error list" and all the other extensive windows in Visual Studio.

Where can I find documentation on add-ins with such user-interfaces to get me started? I can only find documentation on the actual coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that what I needed was Visual Studio 2010 packages.

Fear not, these packages can be made in managed languages too (C# and Visual Basic). However, they require the Visual Studio 2010 SDK, which I didn't have installed.

It's very easy to make, and is done without hassle! Furthermore, it's cool, since the UI of the addins allow WPF!

Answer (score 1):

Although there is some Microsoft documentation for writing add-ins, I recommend you start at Carlos Quintero's Resources about [Visual Studio .NET extensibility](http://www.mztools.com/resources_vsnet_addins.aspx).  There are many how-to articles and links to a variety of documentation.

Comment: Useful, and helped me a bit on the way, but not quite what I was looking for.